# Set navigation item title on a TableViewController child of UISideMenuNavigationController not working

Tags: swift, uinavigationitem

I am trying to set a title to my rootViewController programmatically but it is not working.

```
func configurarMenuRightNavigationController() {

        SideMenuManager.menuFadeStatusBar = false

        let menuRightNavigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightMenuNavigationController") as! UISideMenuNavigationController

        //let menuRightNavigationController = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)
        // UISideMenuNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController, so do any additional configuration
        // of it here like setting its viewControllers. If you're using storyboards, you'll want to do something like:

        SideMenuManager.menuRightNavigationController = menuRightNavigationController

        SideMenuManager.menuRightNavigationController?.viewControllers[0].navigationItem.title = "Teste"

        SideMenuManager.menuPresentMode = .viewSlideOut
    }
```

The title doesn't change.

It works when I try in another project without Side Menu on a regular UINavigationController.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're trying to change the title on a brand new created navigation controller that *does not have any view controllers* yet.  If you do "`if let topViewController = SideMenuManager.menuRightNavigationController?.viewControllers[0]`" and then print something out (or set a break point) if `topViewController` is not nil, does it hit?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but I am not being able to instantiate the right controller. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I created a custom UITableViewController and set it as the view controller of the Table View Controller on the Storyboard.